# How does Android Auto pagination work with media3?

Tags: android, android-auto, android-mediasession, android-media3

So as the question says: I'm trying to get pagination working for Android Auto with media3, but the documentation seems to be either lacking or I can't find it.

I currently have a `MediaService` that extends `MediaLibraryService`

```
class MediaService : MediaLibraryService() {
    // extra code here 

    override fun onGetLibraryRoot(
        session: MediaLibrarySession, 
        browser: ControllerInfo, 
        params: LibraryParams?
    ): ListenableFuture<LibraryResult<MediaItem>> {
        // get root here
    }

    override fun onGetItem(
        session: MediaLibrarySession,
        browser: ControllerInfo,
        mediaId: String
    ): ListenableFuture<LibraryResult<MediaItem>> {
        // get item with id
    }

    override fun onGetChildren(
        session: MediaLibrarySession,
        browser: ControllerInfo,
        parentId: String,
        page: Int,
        pageSize: Int,
        params: LibraryParams?
    ): ListenableFuture<LibraryResult<ImmutableList<MediaItem>>> {
        // get children of item with id
    }


    // extra code here
}
```

The pagination should be achieved with `page` and `pageSize` in `onGetChildren`, but these are always `0` and `Int.MAX_VALUE`. How do you tell Android Auto that it has to ask for different values or that it needs to paginate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more research on the [Android Auto issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130073697) and after asking some questions on the [Media3 Github issue tracker](https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/189) I have discovered that custom pagination for Android Auto is not supported due to the  Driver Distraction guidelines which I think can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/cars/design/design-foundations/interaction-principles).

So based on the comment on the Android Auto issue tracker the number of items returned have to be limited since Android Auto will not send pagination information to Media3. This means that for Android Auto, `page` and `pageSize` arguments of `onGetChildren` can be ignored.

Comment: The lack of pagination is also unfortunate since it makes it easy for replies to apparently exceed internal Binder limits, resulting in log messages like "BpBinder: Large outgoing transaction of 664288 bytes, interface descriptor , code 1", "JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 664288)", and "MBServiceCompat: Calling onLoadChildren() failed for id=... package=com.google.android.projection.gearhead". Media3 seems to silently truncate large replies instead.

Even if Android Auto doesn't show all the items at once, it should probably still request them in batches.